# The system cannot find the file specified - Trying to run Java.exe

Tags: c#, java, windows-server-2008

Here's the code throwing the error:

```
// Run compiler
Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("java.exe", ex);
p.WaitForExit();
```

It's a new server (Windows 2008 R2, IIS7.5), and I installed Java Runtime 7.

I've also set the environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` in system properties to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7` as specified here:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

But it hasn't made any difference.

Any ideas?  The full error is:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +921
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +131
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +45
   Arcade.UploadFunctions.minifyC2Runtime(Int32 GameID) +334
   Arcade.GameFunctions.createGame(Int32 CatID, String Name, String Description, String Instructions, Int32 UserId, Int32 Width, Int32 Height, Int32 ParentGameID) +1345
   ArcadeSubmit.submitGame(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1331
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5352
```

Comment: what about PATH variable did you set it for the whole system as well?

Comment: @Sergey I'm very unfamiliar with Java, do I need to set a PATH variable as well?  My old server had none of these variables set and ran this code fine

Comment: Yes, set the PATH variable. See: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with java overall. It has to do with the system's environment variables. Check your system PATH variable and see if the %JAVA_HOME%/bin is there.

Comment: I followed same link and it mentioned that you need to give path of JDK not JRE.

Comment: @Jason `path` is already set to `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\`

Comment: But java.exe doesn't reside in any of those directories - not in System, not in WindowsPowerShell, not in Microsoft SQL...though I can't see the rest of your PATH. Add the path of the JDK/JRE to PATH.

Comment: @Jason, I'm a bit worried about changing this seemingly important variable, am I correct in saying I should just append `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7;` to the end of `path`?  Also my old server doesn't have Java mentioned in any of it's environmental variables or `path` but it did work.

Comment: `bin` folder has the executables not just JAVA_HOME folder :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it works on your old server. But I do know that appending directories to your PATH isn't harmful. Everytime you specify a file without a directory, Windows checks all the directories in PATH to determine if the file is located there. Adding more directories to PATH just specifies more directories to search under. I mean, at the worst, it might slow down things the tiniest bit.

Comment: @Sergey `path` is now set to `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` but still the same error being thrown.

Comment: `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` too. and type `cmd` from the windows RUN, then type `set` and see if it's there. or just type `java`.

Comment: @Sergey @Jason I now get the error `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Unknown error (0xfffffffe)` when I run the code now, (with jdk..\bin in `path` as well).  Typing `Java` in `cmd` shows a lot of info about Java so that seems to be working

Comment: It looks like there's some sort of incompatibility of 64bit java and your c# executables there...

Comment: yikies. okay looks like you want to compile the JS files with that compiler library then you should try and do the following `java -jar "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Static\arcade\closure\compiler.jar"` then supply your parameters IF this jar has proper manifest and correct main class set there then it should work otherwise you will have to run java in a different way showing a classpath as this jar and calling a main class from it. e.g `java -classpath .;compiler.jar MyMainClass --js .....` and so on provided you're executing it in the same directory with this compiler.jar.

Comment: If you need to run it from your sharp code I would probably recommend to put the whole commandline into a separate .cmd file and run it then from your sharp.

Comment: @sergey sorry you're right I got it wrong, prefixing it with java -jar works, and does everything as expected, it's just not running it from .net

Comment: @TomGullen as I wrote it in my previous comment try and put this long commandline into a .cmd file and just call this .cmd from your c# code.

Comment: @sergey fixed, all working!  I changed the apppoolidentity from networkservice to localservice and everything works dandy, thanks for your help.  If you summated this briefly in an answer I will accept it.  Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TomGullen nah, am not a reputation maniac besides it was a minor issue with the system PATH and the commandline the rest you solved yourself with the IIS' application pool identity.

Comment: @Tom Can you summarize your solution in an answer so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill I'm actually still having difficulties with this, I got it working by giving the app pool `localservice' identity, but after a while it will throw the error again and it will only go back to working when I recycle the app pool